# How to Display the Local image(drawable image file) to cardview via json. I want to load image in offline rather then using picasso library

Tags: java, android, json, android-cardview

How to Display the Local image(drawable image file) to `cardview` via `json`. I want to load image in offline rather then using picasso library

I'm using tab layout And my Frament.java

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    return rootView;


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final ArrayList<Website> babyList = Website.getbabyFromFile("baby&kids.json", getActivity());
    adapter = new WebsiteAdapter(this, babyList);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My Website.java is

```
private String url;
public String imageUrl;

public Website() {
}

public Website(String url)  {
    this.url = url;

}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
public static ArrayList<Website> getbabyFromFile(String filename, Context context) {
    final ArrayList<Website> babyList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Load data
        String jsonString = loadJsonFromAsset("baby&kids.json", context);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray baby = json.getJSONArray("baby&kids");

        // Get Website objects from data
        for(int i = 0; i < baby.length(); i++){
            Website recipe = new Website();

            recipe.setUrl(baby.getJSONObject(i).getString("url"));

            babyList.add(recipe);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return babyList;

}
private static String loadJsonFromAsset(String filename, Context context) {
    String json = null;

    try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(filename);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return json;
}
```

And this is my WebsitAdapter.java

```
private Fragment mContext;
// private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<Website> mDataSource;
OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;


public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    //each data item is just a string in this case

    public TextView url;
    public ImageView thumbnailImageView;
    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        url = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.websitename_id);
        thumbnailImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.website_image_id);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Webview.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra("url", url.getText().toString());

        mContext.startActivity(detailIntent);

    }





}
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(View view, int Position);
}

public void SetOnItemClickListner(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener){
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}
public WebsiteAdapter(Fragment context, ArrayList<Website> items) {
    mContext = context;
    mDataSource = items;
    // mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cardview_item_website, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WebsiteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // - get element from arraylist at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element

    Website website = mDataSource.get(position);

    holder.url.setText(website.getUrl());
    //Picasso.with(mContext).load(website.imageUrl).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.thumbnailImageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSource.size();
}
```

And My output is

[image]

Please give me a solution that if theres is any possible ways to display images that is stored on drawable folder

Comment: where from do you want to load image?

Comment: from drawable folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have local images under drawable folder for all a) **myntra** b) **firstCry** c) **hopscotch** etc. Then you just simply need to get the correct drawable based on url.
You can create Factory class which will give you the `@DrawableRes`

```
    public static @DrawableRes int getDrawable(String url){
        if(url.contains("Myntra")) {
            return R.drawable.myntra;
        } else if(url.contains("Snapdeal")) {
            return R.drawable.snapdeal;
        }
        // Add other if else to support other website url
    }
```

Here is the modified onBindViewHolder method.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WebsiteAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   Website website = mDataSource.get(position);
   holder.url.setText(website.getUrl());
   holder.thumbnailImageView.setImageResource(getDrawable(website.getUrl()));
}
```

Comment: it shows me error on recipe.getUrl() thumbnailImageView.setImageResource(getDrawable(recipe.getUrl()));

Comment: replace that line in onBindViewHolder with `holder.thumbnailImageView.setImageResource(getDrawable(website.getUrl()));`. Look at the updated answer

Comment: Look at the updated answer, added entire `onBindViewHolder` method

Comment: @TechAk Awesome ! Thank you.

Comment: so, krishna now i want to show the images for all the fragments....that shown on the screenshot above like travel,food...etc., after i implement the updated code provided by you it works fine for one particular fragment if i try to do this for all fragments i shoes me a error.